# Security concern in model's of cloud services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

Data -- A perfect figure and shows the characteristics of any individual. When it comes to security, it's a null hypothesis statement " The data is secured ". We are believing it, the statement is true and how sure the organizational data is secured with the cloud.

Even though there is a security concern in all the three models of cloud services --
SaaS vs PaaS vs IaaS models
. How can we handle the data secured with **High-reliability, maintain resource and cost-effective**?

Comment: Your question is a thesis topic!

Answer (score 0):

Google values customers data and commits to uphold trust to the highest degree. [see terms of service](https://cloud.google.com/terms/) and [security and privacy](https://cloud.google.com/security/privacy). As Google puts security to the forefront, the onus is on the user to ensure that they are using the necessary tools (Provided by google) and steps to secure resources. [Google Infrastructure Security Design](https://cloud.google.com/security/infrastructure/design/)   will explain what is managed on their part, but implementing other means of securing resources she be done on the clients part as well.